# How to change prompt color in C shell after command failure?

Tags: colors, solaris, prompt, csh

I tried to change prompt color in bash depending on last command return value. for example prompt turns green if command is success. Or prompt turns red is command fails. Now I am trying to implement same in solaris csh, where can I put condition to check return value of last executed command ?

Comment: if you got it to work in `bash`, then you should include that code in your Q. If you don't have bash on your solaris machine, you should have `ksh` where /usr/xpg4/bin/ksh should give you similar abilities for programming. If `bash` has some built-in support for these manipulations (that I am not aware of (which is quite possible) ) , then this will be more difficult. In any case it will be much more difficult in `csh`. Good luck.

Comment: Does `csh` even support colors?